# Exchange Service - EWS - Only works on localhost

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am using EWS GetUserAvailability and everything works on localhost, but when push my code to a server, I get the following error message:

> The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (401)
>   Unauthorized.

Why is this not working on my server, but on localhost only?

Here is my code:

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("username","password");
service.Url = new Uri("https://mail.mydomain.com/ews/exchange.asmx");
service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

List<AttendeeInfo> attendees = new List<AttendeeInfo>();

            attendees.Add(new AttendeeInfo()
            {
                SmtpAddress = "b@mydomain.com",
                AttendeeType = MeetingAttendeeType.Room
            });

            attendees.Add(new AttendeeInfo()
            {
                SmtpAddress = "bl@mydomain.com",
                AttendeeType = MeetingAttendeeType.Room
            });

AvailabilityOptions availabilityOptions = new AvailabilityOptions();
            availabilityOptions.GoodSuggestionThreshold = 49;
            availabilityOptions.MaximumNonWorkHoursSuggestionsPerDay = 0;
            availabilityOptions.MaximumSuggestionsPerDay = 2;

            availabilityOptions.MeetingDuration = 60;
            availabilityOptions.MinimumSuggestionQuality = SuggestionQuality.Good;
            availabilityOptions.DetailedSuggestionsWindow = new TimeWindow(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1));
            availabilityOptions.RequestedFreeBusyView = FreeBusyViewType.FreeBusy;

            GetUserAvailabilityResults results = service.GetUserAvailability(attendees,
                                                                             availabilityOptions.DetailedSuggestionsWindow,
                                                                             AvailabilityData.FreeBusyAndSuggestions,
                                                                             availabilityOptions);
```

I have also tried:

```
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("username\\DOMAINNAME","password");

service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("username","password", "DOMAINNAME");

service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("username@mydomain.com","password");
```

None of them worked.

Answer (score -1):

The issue was I had UseDefaultCredentials set to true, which it appears uses the AD credentials. When I set it false and set my credentials it works.